# Jquery UI Datepicker - to show date ONLY, but to pass date AND time

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

Is the above possible?

Or does this basically record what it shows to the user? I need to pass date and time to the database, but only to show date to the user.

Comment: Do you mean you need to allow user to choose and set a time, or you just need the date but the data type in your db is "datetime"?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to achieve this by using the plugin [datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/):

I've simply defined a `dateFormat` and set the `timeFormat`to nothing. Internally, it retains the time and you can even select another one, but it does not display.

The only flaw I currently see is that the selected time does not appear in the popup dialog if you don't specify `timeFormat`. But tweaking the plugin by adding an option should not be too difficult.

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/ayV3r/3/).